# jQuery replace text with alt tag when changing img

Tags: jquery

I am basically trying to replace the text on the large img with the alt text of the thumbnail after replacing them using jquery but i cant make it work.

Here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.small-img').click(function() {
    var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');
    $('#lgPic').attr('src', imgsrc);
    $('#lgTitle').prop("alt");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="gallery">
  <img src='img.jpg' id="lgPic" alt="picture 1 "><br>
  <span id="lgTitle">Yellow PomPom Mum</span>

  <div id="thumbs">
    <img class="small-img" src="img1.jpg " alt="picture 2" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I would appretiate all the help!, thanks

Comment: The alt text of the small image is `this.alt`, of which you have a typo on the closing `"`

Comment: $('#lgTitle').text($(this).attr('alt')); ?

Comment: `$('#lgTitle').prop("alt");` does nothing and a span has no `alt`

Comment: `$(this).attr('src')` could also just be `this.src`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `$('#lgTitle').text($(this).attr('alt'));` to jQuery fixed the issue

HTML

```
 <div id="gallery">
      <img src='img.jpg' id="lgPic" alt=picture 1"><br>
      <span id="lgTitle">Yellow PomPom Mum</span>

      <div id="thumbs">
        <img class="small-img" src="img1.jpg" alt="picture 2>
      </div>
 </div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $('.small-img').click(function() {
            var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');
            $('#lgPic').attr('src', imgsrc);
            $('#lgTitle').text($(this).attr('alt'));
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$('#lgTitle').prop("alt");` will return the `alt` property of the element with id equal `#lgTitle`, in your case it will return nothing since the `span` has no `alt`.

If you want to change the text value you should use `.text()` function like :

```
$('#lgTitle').text($(this).attr('alt'));
```